# Analysing features of text in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, pca, autoencoder

I am relatively new to TensorFlow and the idea of auto-encoders, but I was trying create an auto-encoder for text and I didn't want to write this code because it measures token by token.

```
array = array(shape=(2000,20))

model = keras.sequential()
model.add(Dense(20))
model.add(Dense(5))
model.add(Dense(20))

model.compile(optimizer = 'Adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(array, array, epochs = epochs)
```

This code isn't ideal because it tries to reconstruct the text piece by piece, which would be fine for images but not for text because it relies on what came before it. Is there a way to have a neural network compare the conceptual similarities of the output and input, similar to PCA with the components being the encoded layer. Or is there a way to store components of a text without an auto-encoder like in this video?    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ry6S-Dc2X8     http://codeparade.net/classes/

I want to make the conceptual difference between the output and the input be the loss instead of accuracy with tokens. He mentions something about PCA(principal component analysis) in the video.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that instead of defining the loss based on if it got each token correct, I could have it guess a one hot encoded version of the sample, which shows that it can identify the sample without trying to spell. Like this

```
array = array(shape=(2000,20))
onehot = array(1-2000, shape = (2000, 2000))

model = keras.sequential()
model.add(Dense(20))
model.add(Dense(5))
model.add(Dense(20))
model.add(Dense(2000))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(array, onehot, epochs = epochs)
```